# Graph of polynomial, scaling y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to TikZ and to this site, so forgive me if a similar question has already been asked.

I'd like to graph the polynomial function f defined by f(x) = x<sup>3</sup> - 6x<sup>2</sup>. I want the y-axis scaled so that the graph of f fits. (I had to manually change the numbers on the y-axis. Such a noob, I know.) If I don't plot the graph of f, I have a nice, centered coordinate system. Adding the function messes up everything. Can someone help me with this? Here is my current setup:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
%The following places numerals along the x-axis
\coordinate (-5 on x)   at  (0,5);
\node [below left]  at  (-5 on x)   {\small $-5$};
\coordinate (-4 on x)   at  (1,5);
\node [below left]  at  (-4 on x)   {\small $-4$};
\coordinate (-3 on x)   at  (2,5);
\node [below left]  at  (-3 on x)   {\small $-3$};
\coordinate (-2 on x)   at  (3,5);
\node [below left]  at  (-2 on x)   {\small $-2$};
\coordinate (-1 on x)   at  (4,5);
\node [below left]  at  (-1 on x)    {\small $-1$};
\coordinate (0 on x)    at  (5,5);
\node [below left]  at  (0 on x)    {\small $0$};
\coordinate (1 on x)    at  (6,5);
\node [below left]  at  (1 on x)    {\small $1$};
\coordinate (2 on x)    at  (7,5);
\node [below left]  at  (2 on x)    {\small $2$};
\coordinate (3 on x)    at  (8,5);
\node [below left]  at  (3 on x)    {\small $3$};
\coordinate (4 on x)    at  (9,5);
\node [below left]  at  (4 on x)    {\small $4$};
\coordinate (5 on x)    at  (10,5);
\node [below left]  at  (5 on x)    {\small $5$};

%The following places numerals along the y-axis
\coordinate (-40 on y)  at  (5,0);
\node [below left]  at  (-40 on y)  {\small $-40$};
\coordinate (-32 on y)  at  (5,1);
\node [below left]  at  (-32 on y)  {\small $-32$};
\coordinate (-24 on y)  at  (5,2);
\node [below left]  at  (-24 on y)  {\small $-24$};
\coordinate (-16 on y)  at  (5,3);
\node [below left]  at  (-16 on y)  {\small $-16$};
\coordinate (-8 on y)   at  (5,4);
\node [below left]  at  (-8 on y)   {\small $-8$};
\coordinate (8 on y)    at  (5,6);
\node [below left]  at  (8 on y)    {\small $8$};
\coordinate (16 on y)   at  (5,7);
\node [below left]  at  (16 on y)   {\small $16$};
\coordinate (24 on y)   at  (5,8);
\node [below left]  at  (24 on y)   {\small $24$};
\coordinate (32 on y)   at  (5,9);
\node [below left]  at  (32 on y)   {\small $32$};
\coordinate (40 on y)   at  (5,10);
\node [below left]  at  (40 on y)   {\small $40$};
%The following draws the grid lines
\draw[help lines] (-0.25,-0.25) 
  grid (10.25,10.25);
%The following draws the x-axis
\draw[line width=1.0pt,->] (-0.5,5) -- (10.5,5) 
  node[right] {$x$}; 
%The following draws the y-axis
\draw[line width=1.0pt,->] (5,-0.5) -- (5,10.5) 
  node[above] {$y$};
\draw[color=blue,domain=-3:5.2] 
  plot (\x+5,{5+(\x*\x*\x/8)-(3*\x)/8}) 
  node[right] {$f(x) = x^3 - 3x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Thanks for providing a code snippet to show that you made an attempt. But, it is better to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 10):

Your domain is too large. So setting it to `domain=-3:3.8` yields decent results.

However, there are other suggestions:

### 1. Use `\foreach`

You should use `\foreach` loops for repetitive tasks.  For instance, code identical to yours that places the labels can more easily be written as (with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble):

```
    %The following places numerals along the x-axis
    \foreach \x in {-5,...,5}{%
        \coordinate (\x on x)   at  ($(\x,5)+(5,0)$);
        \node [below left]  at  (\x on x)   {\small $\x$};
    }%

    %The following places numerals along the y-axis
    \foreach \y in {-40,-32,...,40}{%
        \coordinate (\y on y)   at  ($(5,\y/8)+(0,5)$);
        \node [below left]  at  (\y on y)   {\small $\y$};
    }%
```

### 2. Use `pgfplots` for plotting.

This greatly simplifies these kinds of tasks. Below is a minimal example of your code which produces:

[image]

### References:

- [Consistently specify a Function and use it for computation and plotting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\FunctionF(#1){(#1)^3- 3*(#1)}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-45,
        ymax=45,
        height=12.0cm,
        width=12.0cm,
        grid,
        xtick={-5,...,5},
        ytick={-40,-32,...,40},
    ]
    \addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=50, mark=none, ultra thick, blue] {\FunctionF(x)};
    \node [left, blue] at (axis cs: 3.6,42) {$x^3-3x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

With tkz-fct (and gnuplot), it's easy  ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-40,ymax=40,ystep=8]   
  \tkzGrid
  \tkzAxeXY
  \tkzFct[color=blue,thick,domain = -5:5]{x**3-3*x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]