# Why is parskip zero inside a tabular?

Tags: tables, parskip

I wonder why `\parskip` is zero inside the tabular environment.

How can i make the paragraphs to be **equally vertically spaced** inside the tabular environment, just like outside the `tabular`?

I know about `\@parboxrestore` and `\@minipagerestore`, but could not find a reference to fix this inside `\begin{tabular}`.

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}

\begin{document}

\textbf{par inside tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{8cm}|}
\hline 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\textbf{par outside tabular}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Leads to the following result:

[image: Example]

Comment: Related Question: [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/why-is-parskip-zero-inside-a-minipage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `minipage` and `\parbox` reset `\parskip` to 0pt, so you will have to reset it inside.  While in this case we know `\parskip=8pt`, in general that will not be true.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\newlength{\oldparskip}

\begin{document}

\textbf{par inside tabular}

\oldparskip=\parskip
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\parskip=\oldparskip}p{8cm}|}
\hline 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: reset parskip]

Comment: `\let\myparskip\parskip` will not save the value of `\parskip`. One can definitely have more than one paragraph in a `\parbox`, why not?

Comment: @egreg - Thanks, learn something every day.  When I used \parbox in the revised solution, \par did nothing, although it works fine outside tabular.

Comment: Thanks but it seems that this solution causes some new problems - in your screenshot you see the first and last line are offset and collide with the table border. Is there some way to achieve without using parbox or minipage?

Comment: why use a minipage here rather than just a normal `p` column?

Comment: `>{\begin{minipage}{8cm}\raggedright\parskip=8pt}{c}<{\end{minipage}}` could more simply (and better vertical spacing) be `>{\raggedright\parskip=8pt}p{8cm}`

Comment: @David Carlisle - If I had known it would be that simple,I wouldn't have bothered.

Answer (score 4):

A `p` column is essentially identical to a `\parbox`. In both cases they use `\@arrayparboxrestore` to normalise several things. If you don't want parskip and parindent normalized but left as in the main document just redefine the command not to reset them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}

\makeatletter
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\textbf{par inside tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{8cm}|}
\hline 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\textbf{par outside tabular}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this is the technically most correct and most generic answer, i prefer the other solution. I wonder if overwriting `\@arrayparboxrestore` may cause new problems, i.e. with packages that depend on their own version of `\@arrayparboxrestore`.

Comment: @Kali I would be inclined to do something like `\NewCommandCopy{\old@arrayparboxrestore}{\@arrayparboxrestore}` followed by `\RenewDocumentCommand{\@arrayparboxrestore}{}{\old@arrayparboxrestore\parskip 8pt}` which would alleviate your concerns.