# minipage messes up spacings

Tags: spacing, minipage, titlesec

I have some troubles with spacing when using `minipages` to keep some content together.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    head=20mm,
    left=20mm,
    right=10mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    foot=8mm
}
\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{opensans} %Schriftart FEHLER
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}                       % use package booktabs for easy creating tables
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}      % to have a dedicated notes section after tables
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt}

\linespread{1.0}   
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                 % verhindert Absatzeinrueckung nach Bildern

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{% <- needed
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt}% <- needed
\colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3%
} 
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{336699}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={color=white}}    % Rechtsbündige Tabellen und Bildbeschreibung
\captionsetup[figure]{format=labelstyle, labelfont={color=white}, 
justification=raggedright,% <- only needed if longer captions should not be justified
singlelinecheck=false% <- added
}

% SECTION STYLE
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\thesection}{1em}{} %\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thesection}{1em-Abstand}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\large\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{} %\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thesection}{1em-Abstand}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} %\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thesection}{1em-Abstand}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\newcommand{\astroltable} { 
    \captionsetup{type=table, format=labelstyle}
    \arrayrulecolor{blue} 
    % \aboverulesep = 0mm 
    % \belowrulesep = 0mm 
    }

    \newenvironment{tableenv}[2]{
        \everypar{}
        \def\tablecaption{#1}
        \def\tablelabel{tab:#2}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{footnotesize} 
                \astroltable
                \begin{threeparttable}
    }{
            \end{threeparttable}
            \caption{\tablecaption}
            \label{\tablelabel}
        \end{footnotesize}
    \end{center}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \blindtext
    \begin{tableenv}{blubb}{blubb}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}Xp{0.075\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{City}  & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{min.} & \textbf{typ.} & \textbf{max.} & \textbf{Rate} \\ \midrule
            New York             & US and A               & -             & 1.0             & -            & n/a            \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{tableenv}
\end{minipage}

\strut
\blindtext
\begin{tableenv}{blubb2}{blubb2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}Xp{0.075\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{City}  & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{min.} & \textbf{typ.} & \textbf{max.} & \textbf{Rate} \\ \midrule
        New York             & US and A               & -             & 1.0             & -            & n/a            \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{tableenv}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

One problem is the missing space above `Table 1`, this is introduced with the use of the `titlesec` package and seems to be caused if the `minipage` starts with a `sectiontitle`. Is there a way to correct this?
The other problem is the space between the caption of `Table 1` and the following text which is different from `Table 2`.

Comment: I suspect your issue has something to do with this: [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64982/4301).

Comment: With the restoring of the `\parskip` I can address the 2nd issue, but it causes the skip before `Table 2` behave the same way as `Table 1` then no matter if I use the `titlesec` package or not.

Comment: The minipage there is vertically centred so the section just sees a following line with very great height so has no chance to adjust the spacing for teh following subsection, and the subsection being in a box has no chance to detect the space coming from the section heading above. (the `\strut` at the start of the paragraph won't affect the spacing there as the usual baselineskip is in effect). The page won't break after a section heading or within the table, s do you need the minipage at all?

Comment: I need the `minipage` to keep the text and the table together. What would be a proper way of grouping Latex elements (paragraphs, tables, figures etc.)? Manually adding `\pagebreaks` is not what I want to end up with in a 200 pages document.

Comment: You might also consider using \vbox{...}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the issues you've encountered are all that closely related to the use of a `minipage` environment. Instead, I would argue, the issues appear to be related to shortcomings in the definitions of the `\astroltable` macro and the `tableenv` environment. The fact that you define the `tabularx` environments to contain 7 columns, but then only use 6 columns, doesn't exactly help either.

Does the layout shown in the following screenshot come closer to meeting your objectives?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
    head=20mm,foot=8mm,
    left=20mm,right=10mm,
    top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
}

\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{opensans}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{% 
    \setlength\fboxsep{3pt}%
    \colorbox{myblue}{{#1}}#2#3}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,
    labelfont={color=white}}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=labelstyle,
    labelfont={color=white},
    justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=false}


\usepackage{titlesec}
% SECTION STYLE
\titleformat{\section}{%
    \Large\bfseries\color{myblue}}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{%
    \large\bfseries\color{myblue}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{%
    \bfseries\color{myblue}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}


\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{336699}

\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%\linespread{1.0} % better: "\singlespacing"

%%%%\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}  % shouldn't be needed

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}   
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\newcommand{\astroltable}{%
    \captionsetup{type=table, format=labelstyle,
        skip=0.75\baselineskip} % <-- new (default is 1\baselineskip)
    \arrayrulecolor{myblue}}

\newenvironment{tableenv}[2]{% quite a few changes here
    \par\medskip
    \def\tablecaption{#1}
    \def\tablelabel{tab:#2}
    \footnotesize % \footnotesize is a macro, not an environment
    \astroltable
    \begin{threeparttable}
    }{%
    \caption{\tablecaption}
    \label{\tablelabel}
    \end{threeparttable} % place this *after* \caption and \label
    }

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \blindtext
    \begin{tableenv}{blubb}{blubb}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
         p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.3\textwidth} *{4}{X}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{City} & \textbf{Country} & 
    \textbf{min.} & \textbf{typ.} & 
    \textbf{max.} & \textbf{Rate} \\
    \midrule
    New York & US and A & -- & 1.0 & -- & n/a \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{tableenv}
\end{minipage}

    \blindtext
    \begin{tableenv}{blubb2}{blubb2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
         p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.3\textwidth} *{4}{X}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{City} & \textbf{Country} & 
    \textbf{min.} & \textbf{typ.} & 
    \textbf{max.} & \textbf{Rate} \\
    \midrule
    New York & US and A & -- & 1.0 & -- & n/a \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{tableenv}

    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great! Can you quickly explain why the `\par` is needed inside the `tableenv`?

Comment: @po.pe - I inserted `\par` mainly as a replacement for `\everypar{}`, whose purpose I'm afraid I don't understand. The `\par` ("paragraph break")  directive is thrown in as a precaution, in case that there's no paragraph break immediately before start of the `tableenv` environment. (Aside: the `\blindtext` directive does insert a paragraph break after it ends.)

Comment: @Mico - \everypar{code} executes the code at the start of every paragraph.  \@afterheading uses it to not indent the next paragraph (then shut itself off).  wrapfig uses it to add \parshape to each paragraph.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks for this explanation. So, what does `\everypar{}` do? Does it force a paragraph break? Might it have advantages over just running `\par` (as I propose doing in my answer)?

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks. My question was much more basic (simple-minded?): What does `\everypar{}` do?

Comment: `\everypar{}` (no code) erases the previous \everypar definition.