# Spacing when using parskip and thmtools

Tags: theorems, thmtools, parskip

I have the following really specific issue, which is probably just a bug in the thmtools package, but I'm wondering if I can work around it.

Basically, if I include the `parskip` package and try to use the `shaded` style of the `thmtools` package, then the vertical spacing inside the theorem environment gets messed up, with all the blank space disappearing between paragraphs and between items of enumerated lists, like this:

[image]

Is there a way that I can fix this issue?

Here's the MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[shaded]{theorem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
The following is an enumerated list: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{enumerate}

This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
\end{theorem}

Here is the same content outside of a theorem environment:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{enumerate}

This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not really a bug of `thmtools`. When using the `shaded` style, `thmtools` loads the `shadethm` package, and wrap the theorem with the `shadebox` environment of the `shadethm` package.

The `shadebox` environment typeset its content inside `minipage`, which by default has `\parskip=0pt` inside of it (see [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64982/264024)).

Fortunately, the `shadebox` environment has a hook called `\shadesetinsideminipage` which restores `\parindent` inside `shadebox`, so we can make him restore `\parskip` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[shaded]{theorem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newlength\saveparskip
\setlength\saveparskip\parskip
\renewcommand\shadesetinsideminipage{%
    \setlength\parindent\saveparindent % \saveparindent is defined inside `shadethm' package
    \setlength\parskip\saveparskip     % this line restores \parskip
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        The following is an enumerated list: 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
            \item three
        \end{enumerate}
        
        This is a paragraph.
        
        This is another paragraph.
    \end{theorem}
    
    Here is the same content outside of a theorem environment:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{enumerate}
    
    This is a paragraph.
    
    This is another paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]