# How to make latex parse `x` as an argument of a macro definition instead of `#1`

Tags: macros, pgfplots, tex-core

When I define a mathematical function for plotting in `pgfplots` or `pstricks` I usually to it in the following way:

```
\def\f(#1){(#1)^3 + 3*exp(#1)}
```

just as suggested by Jake in his answer to a question about [how to define a function consistently for plotting and computations in `pgfplots` with and without `gnuplot`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting).

However is it possible to define say `\defF` such I can write:

```
\defF\f(x){x^3 + 3*exp(x)}
```

which should be equivalent to the first definition using `\def` and `#1` above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: are you sure you gain in code readability?

Long answer: yes, it can be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\functiondef}{mr()m}
 {% #1 = function name (a macro), #2 = variable, #3 = formula
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b#2\b } { \cP\#1 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_gset:cV { function_inner_\cs_to_str:N #1 :n } \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_new:Npn #1 ( ##1 )
   {
    \use:c { function_inner_\cs_to_str:N #1 :n } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_gset:Nn { cV }

\cs_set_eq:NN \eval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\functiondef\f(x){x^3 + 3*exp(x)}

\begin{document}

\eval{\f(42)}

\end{document}
```

Here I use `\fp_eval:n`, adapt it to PGF.

[image]

If I do

```
echo '42^3+3*e(42)' | bc -l
```

I get

```
5217824824561577230.18404391083370567842
```

The accuracy depends, of course, on the number crunching engine.

---

### Explanation

The replacement text is stored in a sequence; every appearance of `x` (the stated variable name, more generally) surrounded by word boundaries is replaced by `#1`. This token list is then passed to `\cs_gset:cV` that builds a regular macro named `\function_inner_f:n` (the actual name is built from the first argument to `\functiondef`) and then the macro `\f` with the argument surrounded by parentheses is defined to use `\function_inner_f:n`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. And yes I think that the code gains readability. In some cases I can also use directly copy and paste without doing a (admittedly simple) search and replace step (x -> #1).

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\def\f(x){x^3 + 3*Euler^x}
\begin{document}

\psPrintValue[algebraic,valuewidth=20]{42,\f(x)}

\end{document}
```

[image]