# Easiest way to plot a function with PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to TikZ and/or PGF (whatever the difference is :/), as you can see. Anyway, I need to draw the graph of the equation `x^(2/3) + y^(2/3) = a^(2/3)`, where `a = 2`.
Any suggestions? Here is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
Some text goes here.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    % Draw x-axis
    \draw[very thick,->] (-3,0) -- (3.5,0)
            node[right] {$x$}; 
    % Draw y-axis
    \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3.5) 
        node[above] {$y$};
    % Draw graph of equation
        \draw[smooth, color=blue, domain=-3:3, ultra thick, line cap=butt, samples=400]
            plot (\x,{ (2^{2/3} - (\x)^{2/3} )^{3/2} });
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While `tikz` can do basic graphs, it is more of  drawing package than a graphing package.  For graphs, I would recommend you use [the `pgfplots` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), which  internally uses `tikz` to do the actual drawing.  To use `pgfplots` you invoke the `axis` environment.

The following graph in blue is the function you had in your MWE:

[image]

Based on the math explained in ガベージコレクタ's solution, I have parmaterically graphed the solution to the original equation:

[image]

### Notes:

- Using `pgfmathdeclarefunction` isn't required, but makes it easier to read.
- This solution in the MWE has a discontinuity at 0, so if you use `unbounded coords=discard`, you will see messages of the sort:

  > coordinate (2Y7.559544e-3],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y)

  These go away if you use `unbounded coords=jump`.
- There have been a few cases where I needed to rewrite the expressions such as this as

  ```
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{Function}{1}{%
      \pgfmathparse{exp((3/2)*ln( 2^(2/3) - exp((1/3)*ln(#1)) ))}}
  ```

  but it does not appear to be necessary in this case.

  Thought I would point it out in case you run into problems with other similar expressions.
- Also, it should be noted that `pgf` trigonometric functions expect the parameter to be in degrees, hence the use of the `deg()` function in the parametric graph.

### References:

- There are a few cases where you need to use the math engine in `gnuplot` to generate the points, in which case it is useful to be able to [Consistently specify function to be graphed with or without gnuplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32750/consistently-specify-function-to-be-graphed-with-or-without-gnuplot).
- If you like the method of defining a separate function using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`, and you want to be able to use this new function for computations, you should refer to [Consistently specify a Function and use it for computation and plotting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

\newcommand*{\A}{2}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Function}{1}{% as per original MWE
  \pgfmathparse{(2^(\A) - (#1)^(1/3) )^(3/2)}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{SolutionX}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\A*(cos(deg(\t)))^3}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{SolutionY}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\A*(sin(deg(\t)))^3}%
}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, ultra thick, samples=400}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=discard]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=blue, domain=0:3] (\x,{Function(\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xmin=-2.5, xmax = 2.5, ymin=-2.5, ymax = 2.5]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=red,  variable=\t, domain=-2*pi:0] 
        ({SolutionX(\t)},{SolutionY(\t)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: could you add some explanation about the difference between TikZ and pgf as the OP seems a little unsure :)

Comment: @cmhughes: Ok, added a brief blurb. Let me know if you think that is sufficient.

Comment: @Peter Grill: +1. I find your answer better, because you are using pgfplots.  -but as you can see in the other answer your solution is not complete.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Yes I see how the math portion should be corrected but I was focused on the TeX part and showing how to graph an equation, not how to solve it. But will fix the math as well soon.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Have up updated solution.

Comment: Thanks, all, especially you, Peter! I appreciate all the time you put into my question.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=300}

\def\a{2}
\def\x(#1){\a*cos(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){\a*sin(#1)^3}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=red]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

With PSTricks the solution is as follows,

[image]

### Animated version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=300}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPeval\Delta{round(2*pi/30:2)}

\def\a{2}
\def\x(#1){\a*cos(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){\a*sin(#1)^3}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.00+\Delta}{31}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=red]{0}{\n}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

### With implicit function plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-2)(2,2)
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.05,algebraic](-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1){(x^2)^(1/3)+(y^2)^(1/3)-4^(1/3)}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am still trying to learn how to use the packages you used in your solution. I am unable to get LaTeX to reproduce your same results. I'll keep working on it though. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Nathan: use xelatex or latex-dips-ps2pdf rather than pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

While I have been using Ti*k*Z a little bit over the last couple of years, I  am brand new to `pgf`, per se, and `tikzmath`.  I have a number of questions, but for now, out of simple curiosity, since Nathan was new to "tikz and/or pgf" why didn't you just tell him to use

```
\draw [ scale=0.5, domain=-3.142:3.142, smooth, variable=\t ]
plot ( {2*cos(\t r)^3}, {2*sin(\t r)^3} );
```

or:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={xx(\t) = 2*cos(\t)^3; yy(\t) = 2*sin(\t)^3;}]
    \draw [scale=0.5] plot [ domain=0:360, samples=73, smooth ] ( {xx(\x)}, {yy(\x)} );
```

Comment: Welcome, this seems to be better suited as a comment. Soon you will have enough reputation points to leave comments, for now the team will convert this.