# A PostScript error when plotting an implicit function

Tags: pstricks, pst-func

This question was inspired by [my answer for another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74586/9467). I want to provide another solution with implicit function plot. Unfortunately the following code produces PostScript errors `/undefinedresult in --exp--`. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.2,algebraic](-2,-2)(2,2){x^(2/3)+y^(2/3)-2^(2/3)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how should it be done? (-2)^0.667  is not possible, write it as `(x^2)^(1/3)`

use

```
\psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1,     
           algebraic](-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1){(x^2)^0.333+(y^2)^0.333-4^0.333}
```

[image]

and as already mentioned in the documentation use a clipping area smaller than the iteration area, which is needed to clip all the "moveto" lines, which could be seen in Heikos answer:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-2)(2,2)
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1,
    algebraic](-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1){(x^2)^0.333+(y^2)^0.333-4^0.333}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The ghostscript interpreter has a little trouble to print the plot partially in the imaginary space. The range for `x` and `y` include negative numbers and the exponent is not an integer number. That is not supported by `exp` operator of [PostScript](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf):

> **exp**: *base* *exponent* **exp** *real*
>
> raises *base* to the *exponent* power. The operands may be either
>   integers or r numbers. If the exponent has a fractional part, the
>   result is meaningful     only if the base is nonnegative. The result
>   is always a real number.
>
> **Examples**
>          9 0.5 exp ⇒  3.0
>             -9 -1 exp ⇒ -0.111111
>
> **Errors**:    **stackunderflow**, **typecheck**, **undefinedresult**

In your case you get the latter error `undefinedresult`.
The example works, if the range is limited to non-negative numbers.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.2,algebraic](0,0)(2,2){x^(2/3)+y^(2/3)-2^(2/3)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I will give a bounty of 100 later for this nice answer.