# How to plot the following function using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am new to LaTeX and I want to know how to plot the following function using `TikZ`:

`y = 300 + 1000/x + 2.5x`.

at the interval 0:250

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Does [Easiest way to plot a function with PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74574/easiest-way-to-plot-a-function-with-pgf-tikz) answer your question?

Comment: No not really because of the large interval which includes 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version adapted from [Easiest way to plot a function with PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74574/easiest-way-to-plot-a-function-with-pgf-tikz).

One does not need to use `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`, but I find it easier to maintian code if each function is declared as such.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Function}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{300 + 1000/x + 2.5}%
}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, ultra thick, samples=400}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=discard]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=blue, domain=0:250] (\x,{Function(\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
```