# How can I change font size on x-y labels

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code which I copied from here [How to draw the unit hyperbola in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158968/how-to-draw-the-unit-hyperbola-in-latex), and rotated it. The axis labels font is too large. Going through the manual and deveral posts, am not able to settle my problem. I tried to put {font size=tiny at various location, nothing changes.
Help will be appreciated

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.12}
% axis style, ticks, etc
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={font=\tiny}{
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
axis line style={->}, % arrows on the axis
`xlabel={\footnotesize$x^{'}$},          % default put x `on x-axis
                ylabel={\footnotesize$y^{'}$},{font=\tiny}          % 
default put y on y-axis
                rotate=40.0}}
% arrows as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-5,xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,ymax=5]
        \addplot [red,domain=-2:2] ({cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
    \addplot [red,domain=-2:2] ({-cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
    \addplot[red,dashed] expression {x};
    \addplot[red,dashed] expression {-x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the easiest way is to simply add on of the predefined styles `normalsize`, `small`, `footnotesize` or `tiny` to the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can modify font size of `labels` and `tick labels` with `label style={font=\tiny}` and `tick label style={font=\tiny}`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% axis style, ticks, etc
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
                    label style={font=\tiny},
                    tick label style={font=\tiny}  
                    }}

% arrows as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-5,xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,ymax=5]
        \addplot [red,thick,domain=-2:2] ({cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
        \addplot [red,thick,domain=-2:2] ({-cosh(x)}, {sinh(x)});
        \addplot[red,dashed] expression {x};
        \addplot[red,dashed] expression {-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @salim bou, I inserted the suggested code. The document works but still there is no change in the font.

Comment: You mean `labels` and `tick labels`? answer updated.

Comment: I mean the numbers on the axes

Comment: thanks once more, on a second attempt the font has now changed. I appreciate your help.

Comment: thanks very much, on a second attempt, the fonts changed. I really appreciate your help. Sorry for repeating, I thought did not pass earlier on

Comment: For completeness to Salim's answer, other substitutes for the font style include `\tiny,\small,\normalfont` as defined in the [manual](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=299)