# Plotting an arbitrary function in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to know how I can replicate the diagram below in latex.

thanks.

[image]

Edit: I can plot a function using tikz/pgfplots if I know how the function is defined. Unfortunately, I don't know how the function is defined in this case.

Comment: Use `pgfplots`. See for example [Easiest way to plot a function with PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74574/easiest-way-to-plot-a-function-with-pgf-tikz).

Comment: Can you at least give the function that produces that graph?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina There was no function. Well I guess the function is unknown.

Comment: @Nana Well, you need to have some description of the function before you can plot anything. It seems that your question is more about maths (interpolation, approximation) than about plotting things in LaTeX...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about how to derive a mathematical description for an unknown function than about actually plotting a function in LaTeX. The question may have to be migrated to Maths.SX.

Comment: See also the [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) library by Andrew Stacey, which can be used to assemble a nice-looking curve if you can guess a few points on it.

Comment: @CharlesStaats You should post an answer using `hobby`.  I'd never heard of before.  Just been playing with it because of your comment.  Never nice solution!!

Comment: I have a hobby solution I'll post if the hold on the question is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  domain=-1:7,
  yticklabels=\empty,
  xtick={-1,...,7},
  xticklabels={-1,...,7},
  samples=100
  ]
\addplot[no markers] {-0.1*x*(x-3)*(x-3)*(x-6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Refer to the package documentation to adjust the settings according to your needs.

Comment: I did:

`\documentclass[english,a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-.7:6.7,]
\foreach \x/\xtext in {-1/-1, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6, 7/7}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};
\draw[->] (-1.2,0) -- (7.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-6.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw [samples=200] plot (\x,{-0.1*\x*(\x-3)*(\x-3)*(\x-6)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

and works well also. Sorry, I can't go to newline in comments...?