# Graph a function in TeXStudio

Tags: errors, pst-plot

I want to know how do graph a vector field and a function in TeXStudio.

So far, I have tried:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=300}

\def\a{2}
\def\x(#1){\a*cos(#1)^3}
\def\y(#1){\a*sin(#1)^3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=red]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got some errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...egin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
Undefined control sequence. ...egin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
Undefined control sequence. ...egin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
Undefined control sequence. ...egin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
Undefined control sequence. ...egin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
Undefined control sequence. ...egin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
Undefined control sequence. ...t[linecolor=red]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
Undefined control sequence. ...t[linecolor=red]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
Undefined control sequence. ...t[linecolor=red]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
Undefined control sequence. ...t[linecolor=red]{0}{\psPiTwo}{\x(t)|\y(t)}
```

Also, I read this question [Easiest way to plot a function with PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74574/3954/easiest-way-to-plot-a-function-with-pgf-tikz)
 and copy each code in a new page. All of them don't work.

Can someone tell me why and how to do in TeXStudio?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @Simple I Have tried the MWE you provided and it worked for me. I am using TeXStudio, TeXLive 2014. Can you give us a little more technnical insight on your distribution and OS. Greetings!

Comment: You cannot compile this document with pdflatex; either compile it using xelatex, or use the route `latex->dvi->ps->pdf`.

Comment: Also, TeXstudio has _nothing_ to do with it; it's just the editor.