# Implicit Curve - Descartes's Folium

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to plot a implicit curve. I use tikzpicture and pgf plots. 
The curve is `x^3+y^3-9xy=0`.
Anyone can make an `\addplot[]{}` for the tikzpicture? 
Thanks :D

Comment: You can do a parametric plot, because the curve is rational.

Comment: how can I do? I can fint a parametric form, but don't know how to plot...

Comment: find the parametric form and we'll draw it

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using could help....  Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74574/easiest-way-to-plot-a-function-with-pgf-tikz

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: If yes, then please accept the provided answer.

Answer (score 6):

Cubic curves are parametrizable. You equation, defining [Folium of Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes), has a parametrization as shown in the following code

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikz{
    \draw[samples=200,domain=125:-35]plot(\x:{9*sin(\x)*cos(\x)/(sin(\x)^3+cos(\x)^3)})
         (-9,0)--(9,0)(0,-9)--(0,9);
}

\end{document}
```

[image]